# How do I troubleshoot an https connection problem in a scala call?

Tags: scala, http, ssl, https, netty

I am trying to download my facebook profile image. I successully use oauth to connect and get all the right tokens, and am told by the facebook API the url for my profile image.

However when I try and retrieve it, I get an error about a connection exception. It looks like something in a sslhandler, but Im not sure. I have included some scala code showing how I download the image. I can get it if I change to http, but https fails.

A bit of deeper diving on a different server indicates the problem is due to SSL/TLS validation.

```
Sep 19 12:38:23 ip-172-31-24-217 server: 12:38:23.449 [New I/O worker #2] DEBUG c.n.h.c.p.n.NettyAsyncHttpProvider - Unexpected I/O exception on channel [id: 0x4b7d650e, /172.31.24.217:47572 => scontent-syd2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/157.240.8.23:443]
Sep 19 12:38:23 ip-172-31-24-217 server: org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record:
```

I am using 0.11.2 of the databinder dispatch.

build.sbt

```
name := "url-test"

organization := "dev.undrewb"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Sonatype scala-tools releases"  at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases",
  "Sonatype scala-tools snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
)

libraryDependencies ++= {
  Seq(
    "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.11.2"
  )
}
```

Scala code

```
import dispatch.Defaults._
import dispatch._
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

  def fetchUrl( uri : String ) : Array[Byte] = {
         val svc = url(uri)
         val future_img = Http(svc OK as.Bytes)
         Await.result(future_img, Duration(1, "seconds"))
    
         future_img()
}
```

After I've done sbt console with the build.sbt above, and paste the code above, I get the following - first with https failing then as http working

```
java.net.ConnectException: https://scontent-syd2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/12347856_10153070551591710_2899469599397194349_n.jpg?_nc_cat=105&_nc_sid=dbb9e7&_nc_ohc=1wqEuhGf4S4AX_iqRx5&_nc_ht=scontent-syd2-1.xx&tp=6&oh=4a792c1f0f4eded4ff2516efdfb056ab&oe=5F8D2DC4
  at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyConnectListener.operationComplete(NettyConnectListener.java:103)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:427)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultChannelFuture.java:413)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.setFailure(DefaultChannelFuture.java:380)
  at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelDisconnected(SslHandler.java:641)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:396)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:360)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:58)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:779)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.close(Channels.java:828)
  at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$ClosingChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SslHandler.java:1647)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:427)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.addListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:145)
  at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.closeOutboundAndChannel(SslHandler.java:1607)
  at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handleDownstream(SslHandler.java:580)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:784)
  at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:54)
  at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec.handleDownstream(HttpClientCodec.java:97)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:784)
  at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.handleDownstream(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:109)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:582)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.close(Channels.java:812)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(AbstractChannel.java:197)
  at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.exceptionCaught(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1621)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
  at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.handleUpstream(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:142)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
  at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.exceptionCaught(FrameDecoder.java:377)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
  at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec.handleUpstream(HttpClientCodec.java:92)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
  at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.exceptionCaught(SslHandler.java:692)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:525)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannelSink.exceptionCaught(AbstractChannelSink.java:48)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.notifyHandlerException(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:658)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:566)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
  at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
  at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
  ... 58 more
```

```
scala> fetchUrl("http://scontent-syd2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/12347856_10153070551591710_2899469599397194349_n.
jpg?_nc_cat=105&_nc_sid=dbb9e7&_nc_ohc=1wqEuhGf4S4AX_iqRx5&_nc_ht=scontent-syd2-1.xx&tp=6&oh=4a792c1f0f4eded4ff2516efdfb
056ab&oe=5F8D2DC4")
res2: Array[Byte] = Array(-1, -40, -1, -32, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, -19, 0, -100, 80, 104, 111, 116, 111, 115, 104, 111, 112, 32, 51, 46, 48, 0, 56, 66, 73, 77, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -128, 28, 2, 103, 0, 20, 107, 111, 56, 50, 105, 103, 81, 77, 53, 57, 85, 55, 103, 73, 72, 45, 110, 119, 106, 75, 28, 2, 40, 0, 98, 70, 66, 77, 68, 48, 97, 48, 48, 48, 97, 56, 56, 48, 49, 48, 48, 48, 48, 99, 55, 48, 52, 48, 48, 48, 48, 102, 52, 48, 97, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 98, 48, 99, 48, 48, 48, 48, 53, 102, 48, 100, 48, 48, 48, 48, 57, 99, 49, 52, 48, 48, 48, 48, 99, 56, 49, 100, 48, 48, 48, 48, 55, 57, 49, 101, 48, 48, 48, 48, 98, 101, 49, 102, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 50, 49, 48, 48, 48, 48, 54, 97, 51, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, -1, -37, 0, 67, 0, 6, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, ...
```

The host has a valid cert

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Menlo Park, O = "Facebook, Inc.", CN = *.facebook.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = US, ST = California, L = Menlo Park, O = "Facebook, Inc.", CN = *.facebook.com
   i:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
   i:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEsTCCA5mgAwIBAgIQBOHnpNxc8vNtwCtCuF0VnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBs
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3
d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMSswKQYDVQQDEyJEaWdpQ2VydCBIaWdoIEFzc3VyYW5j
ZSBFViBSb290IENBMB4XDTEzMTAyMjEyMDAwMFoXDTI4MTAyMjEyMDAwMFowcDEL
MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFTATBgNVBAoTDERpZ2lDZXJ0IEluYzEZMBcGA1UECxMQd3d3
LmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbTEvMC0GA1UEAxMmRGlnaUNlcnQgU0hBMiBIaWdoIEFzc3Vy
YW5jZSBTZXJ2ZXIgQ0EwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQC2
4C/CJAbIbQRf1+8KZAayfSImZRauQkCbztyfn3YHPsMwVYcZuU+UDlqUH1VWtMIC
Kq/QmO4LQNfE0DtyyBSe75CxEamu0si4QzrZCwvV1ZX1QK/IHe1NnF9Xt4ZQaJn1
itrSxwUfqJfJ3KSxgoQtxq2lnMcZgqaFD15EWCo3j/018QsIJzJa9buLnqS9UdAn
4t07QjOjBSjEuyjMmqwrIw14xnvmXnG3Sj4I+4G3FhahnSMSTeXXkgisdaScus0X
sh5ENWV/UyU50RwKmmMbGZJ0aAo3wsJSSMs5WqK24V3B3aAguCGikyZvFEohQcft
bZvySC/zA/WiaJJTL17jAgMBAAGjggFJMIIBRTASBgNVHRMBAf8ECDAGAQH/AgEA
MA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBhjAdBgNVHSUEFjAUBggrBgEFBQcDAQYIKwYBBQUHAwIw
NAYIKwYBBQUHAQEEKDAmMCQGCCsGAQUFBzABhhhodHRwOi8vb2NzcC5kaWdpY2Vy
dC5jb20wSwYDVR0fBEQwQjBAoD6gPIY6aHR0cDovL2NybDQuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29t
L0RpZ2lDZXJ0SGlnaEFzc3VyYW5jZUVWUm9vdENBLmNybDA9BgNVHSAENjA0MDIG
BFUdIAAwKjAoBggrBgEFBQcCARYcaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tL0NQ
UzAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUUWj/kK8CB3U8zNllZGKiErhZcjswHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUsT7D
aQP4v0cB1JgmGggC72NkK8MwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBABiKlYkD5m3fXPwd
aOpKj4PWUS+Na0QWnqxj9dJubISZi6qBcYRb7TROsLd5kinMLYBq8I4g4Xmk/gNH
E+r1hspZcX30BJZr01lYPf7TMSVcGDiEo+afgv2MW5gxTs14nhr9hctJqvIni5ly
/D6q1UEL2tU2ob8cbkdJf17ZSHwD2f2LSaCYJkJA69aSEaRkCldUxPUd1gJea6zu
xICaEnL6VpPX/78whQYwvwt/Tv9XBZ0k7YXDK/umdaisLRbvfXknsuvCnQsH6qqF
0wGjIChBWUMo0oHjqvbsezt3tkBigAVBRQHvFwY+3sAzm2fTYS5yh+Rp/BIAV0Ae
cPUeybQ=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=C = US, ST = California, L = Menlo Park, O = "Facebook, Inc.", CN = *.facebook.com

issuer=C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: ECDSA
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3121 bytes and written 384 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
Server public key is 256 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    Session-ID: FBAB4FB69334711C0C8C616688003A1CE0551E64ED120A0FD5C6BFD65F4D2349
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Resumption PSK: CB947853006B7F175038EE259A9D4F38122A42563032F91E39B5D16E20542418
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 172800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 6e d6 67 0a 39 a6 72 35-49 5d 26 dd 9c 94 87 cd   n.g.9.r5I]&.....
    0010 - a8 c3 f1 f6 cc b0 18 35-d9 ab 89 e5 df 59 da 59   .......5.....Y.Y
    0020 - 00 00 00 00 17 02 74 d9-ed d1 a9 57 4a bd 14 f9   ......t....WJ...
    0030 - da 2a 01 69 21 12 3e 60-d7 7b 6a 42 cf eb 2b 5b   .*.i!.>`.{jB..+[
    0040 - a6 4f fe 91 cb f7 2e 57-e0 d6 ad 29 94 3b ae fa   .O.....W...).;..
    0050 - f0 56 f5 63 b5 d9 53 ae-bf 13 96 87 3f a7 fe 78   .V.c..S.....?..x
    0060 - 16 ac 3b ad 73 08 30 d6-a7 22 b9 6c 86 e5 a2 3c   ..;.s.0..".l...<
    0070 - 21 09 e9 0d bb bd 82 12-c0 62 c1 78 ab 97 67 64   !........b.x..gd
    0080 - f3 e4                                             ..

    Start Time: 1600520660
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 4294967295
---
```

Accessing a different https url works fine.

```
scala> fetchUrl("https://www.apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=<removed_my_key>&source=USD")
res7: Array[Byte] = Array(123, 34, 115, 117, 99, 99, 101, 115, 115, 34, 58, 116, 114, 117, 101, 44, 34, 116, 101, 114, 109, 115, 34, 58, 34, 104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 92, 47, 92, 47, 99, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 99, 121, 108, 97, 121, 101, 114, 46, 99, 111, 109, 92, 47, 116, 101, 114, 109, 115, 34, 44, 34, 112, 114, 105, 118, 97, 99, 121, 34, 58, 34, 104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 92, 47, 92, 47, 99, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 99, 121, 108, 97, 121, 101, 114, 46, 99, 111, 109, 92, 47, 112, 114, 105, 118, 97, 99, 121, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 115, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 54, 48, 48, 53, 50, 48, 57, 52, 53, 44, 34, 115, 111, 117, 114, 99, 101, 34, 58, 34, 85, 83, 68, 34, 44, 34, 113, 117, 111, 116, 101, 115, 34, 58, 123, 34, 85, 83, 68, 65, 69, 68, 34, 58, 51, 46, 54, 55, 50,...
scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch databinder is no longer maintained. It is failing because it doesnt recognise TLS 1.3. I should move to something like akka-http.